# Active view on migrated question is broken

Tags: bug, status-completed, migration

If in [this recently migrated question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9363/1235) I sort the answers by "active", then I get the same sorting as for "oldest".

(Incidentally, how come that this old question with no recent answers was migrated? It looks a bit out of place on tex.sx, with 58 upvotes on the top voted answer ...)

Comment: On the question and top answer score: this humble question instantly went in the top 10 by votes, and I don't think there's an answer on TeX.SE that has ever collected 58 upvotes. There should be some sort of adjustment for questions migrated between sites, based on the size difference between them. Otherwise, we risk getting "polluted" with okay-ish questions (and answers) that have gathered a lot of upvotes simply due to the size of the audience they are shown to, not because of their quality.

Comment: @Martin: Exactly this is what I meant. Thanks a lot for spelling out my thoughts.

Comment: Also somewhat strange to migrate a question whose last activity came when TeX.SE was barely conceived.

Comment: @Willie: Exactly. When I saw it, I immediately thought: Are we going to see 1700 migrated old questions soon?

Comment: I'd guess the question was migrated by request of the question-asker (who is also a tex.SE user and has asked several questions here).

Answer (score 9):

The last activity date for migrated answers was being set to the time of the migration, busting the "active" sort.

A fix to retain source answers' last activity date will be pushed out tonight.

Comment: Thanks! I guess the fix will only affect new migrations, and that post I linked to will stay as is, right? (The latter is not a real problem; I'd just like to know.)

Comment: @Hendrik yes, this will only be fixed going forward.