# How to deal with TeX.SE question that is duplicate of a question on another StackExchange site?

Tags: discussion, duplicates, stackexchange

Is it possible to flag a question as a duplicate of a question on another StackExchange site (SE site)? What if the question is closed there as off-topic? For example, see [this question on TeX.SE](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/97941) and a [possible duplicate on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2701902) where [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2703707) is answering both questions.

Migration of an *old* question to TeX.SE will spoil the view counter on TeX.SE and give the question a wrong ranking (see [Policy on migrating questions from another StackExchange site?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/869/24449)). So it seems not an option.

Then there is quoting. One could

1. post a link to the old question / answer, or
2. quote the most appropriate answer literally (that is copy and paste into a quotation block, add the link, mention the author).

Should one use a community wiki instead of an answer to be fair?

To sum up, which technique is recommended in this case?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'd go with option 2, making it CW. We can have a good answer on our site that would make for easier browsing. Migrating the question on SO is out of the question, I'm afraid, since it's quite old.

Answer (score 10):

In this case, in my opinion it makes sense to migrate the question from SO to TeX.SX, polish it by removing the not-an-answers and properly retag. The question is good as it stands, so are the (real) answers there. The one here can then be closed as a duplicate (if it is a duplicate, I'm not an expert in this).

IMHO: Migrating good questions with good answers here, if they clearly belong here (which is obviously the case, since SO closed it as off-topic), makes sense and is valuable for the site.

Comment: _Can_ you migrate questions that are older than one year?

Comment: In cases when migration is not possible (I don't know the policies regarding that) it could be beneficial to the TeX.SE community to create one CW with catalogued links to such TeX-related Q&As on SO, maybe even quoting some crucial parts to make it more useful.