# Moving a TeX topic off SO

Tags: support, scope, migration

New here... shouldn't [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1849667/enumerating-sections-to-start-with-sign) be migrated over to TeX.SX? My reading of that post over there as well as the [accepted policy answer](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/869/policy-on-migrating-questions-from-another-stackexchange-site) over here suggests it probably can be moved it's seems an off-topic there, and should be here instead. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In such cases such posts should be flagged on the current site to be migrated to TeX.SX. We TeX.SX moderators can't do anything from here exact flag it ourselves. However, this particular post seems to be too old for migration, as the flagging dialog tells me.

Comment: OK, thanks. I think it's clear; for now.

Answer (score 2):

These old posts should not be migrated from SO, because:

1. The new policy is against migrating old questions that have already been answered, partly due to problems with the handling of reputation, and also because these migrates are not held to be constructive.  See [How to migrate old questions to a new graduated site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/152597/how-to-migrate-old-questions-to-a-new-graduated-site).  Instead, questions that are off topic on SO should simply be closed.
2. These questions should not be closed as off topic, as questions about how to code up Latex are on topic for SO, just as HTML/CSS questions are.  See dmckee's answer at https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/12926/140179